# How to Load data into bigquery from buckets partitioned with Year/Month/Day

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a data stored on gcp bucket in below format - 
gs:/gcptest/Year=2020/Month=06/day=18/test1.parquet and so many files under the day=18 folder.
I want to create a table in bigquery with the columns present in the files and partitioned by Year,Month,Day that is present on the file path.
So that when I will load the data into table I can just select the path from the gcp bucket and load the data which will partitioned by values of Year/Month/Day present on the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery supports loading externally partitioned data in Avro, Parquet, ORC, CSV and JSON formats that is stored on Cloud Storage using a default hive partitioning layout.

Support is currently limited to the BigQuery web UI, command-line tool, and REST API.

You can see more in [Loading externally partitioned data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/hive-partitioned-loads-gcs) documentation
Also see how to [Query externally partitioned data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/hive-partitioned-queries-gcs)